# How can I respond to an API call with a CSV file? NodeJS

Tags: node.js, csv

I don't know where to start, any help would be appreciated. Here is what I have so far,

```
res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename='+filename);
res.set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
res.send(filename);
```

With the above code, it responses with the filename only. I want to respond with the file attached so that I can get the file in front-end (angular4) and pop up with a downloadable link. Any ideas how can I achieve that?

P.S. I am following this tutorial for the front-end. It says that I have to have `content-disposition` with the file attached in order to make a downloadable link for the file. Not sure if I am doing it right.

https://shekhargulati.com/2017/07/16/implementing-file-save-functionality-with-angular-4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the contents of csv and send it response.

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile(inputPath, function (err, fileData) {
      res.status(200).send(fileData);
  })
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am following this tutorial for the front-end. It says that I have to have `content-disposition` with the file attached in order to make a downloadable link for the file. https://shekhargulati.com/2017/07/16/implementing-file-save-functionality-with-angular-4/

Comment: do you think it would work if I just respond with the content of the file?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use `res.sendFile(inputPath)`?